# How to Update Editable Grid Data using Mass action?

Tags: magento-1.8, grid, grid-serlization, ce-1.9.0.1

I am very confuse How to Update the Editable Grid Data using Mass action.

I tried but it will got only Id in post. any one done this before then please guide me.

Please See the below Image If any one know the answer then let me know.

[image]

Comment: Maybe some you will find some info in the articles:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477792/magento-how-to-submit-an-editable-grid-with-mass-action-or-similar,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728842/magento-admin-grid-sending-data-from-action-to-controller

Comment: Buddy I already do that and editable filed come this is my local machine snap but when you select Action then How to fetch all this values my question is that

Comment: If you already receive the to-be-saved-data matched to the entity IDs in the POST/GET data, you can simply use a model-filter to fetch the appropriate entities and perform data-saves on them. I don't know what the POST/GET data of that editable grid is.

Comment: Buddy I am not satisfied with your answers.

Comment: Then provide more information. What data are you receiving already?

Comment: I reciving only selected rows ds array but I also need that editable fields values.

Comment: http://www.atwix.com/magento/inline-editing-in-magento-backend-grids/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot give you the direct answer but I definitely know the way.

For every admin grid magento creates javascript object `varienGridMassaction`. 
It is defined in `\js\mage\adminhtml\grid.js`.

During selecting checkboxes in grid, `varienGridMassaction` object saves ids of selected rows.

When you select mass action type and press **Submit** button you are not *submitting* form in normal meaning of this word. This button runs `varienGridMassaction::apply()`, which gets all selected ids and sends them with mass action type to the server.

So you cannot simply add `input`s and make them be transferred with usual mass action data.

Possible solutions:

- You can rewrite `varienGridMassaction` to send more data during submit.
- Create one more button and javascript class to process your custom input fields.

Comment: @olekssi Can you guide me via code I am confused

Comment: So which solution you decided to start with? And what exactly code explanation you need?

Comment: Second One Create the button and when we click on that button I want selected rows Editable values.

Comment: In grid container class add one more button using `$this->_addButton()`. Create controller which will process your ajax request. Create javascript function to get data from input fields from grid and send ajax request to your controller. During creating button specify `onclick` attribute with the name of your function.

Comment: I can not add the Button using this $this->_addButton() if possible we can chat and solve my problem